# Why does javascript not recognize the CreateTextFile() function?

Tags: javascript, file

This is some code that I got online to create and write to a file, but when I hover over 'CreateTextFile', it says "Unresolved function or method".

```
function WriteToFile(passForm) {
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var s = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\\test.txt", true);
    s.writeln("HI");
    s.writeln("Bye");
    s.writeln("-----------------------------");
    s.Close();
}
```

Comment: What browser?  ActiveX, as far as I'm aware, is only available in IE.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/JavaScript/Microsoft_Extensions/ActiveXObject

Comment: Yes I'm using IE but it doesn't look like it's working

Comment: What version of IE?

Comment: Version 11.450.19041.0

Comment: I found that the CreateTextFile() is in the ASP.NET language. Do I need to install a plugin?